# How i can solve this error 5.7.8 username and password not accepted. learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=badcredentials magenton

Tags: magento2, smtp

[image]

which email and password should be entered in username and pasword

Comment: I also getting this type error   5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c12sm13612062pfl.56 - gsmtp

Comment: Confirm you configrured your email Id & Password and select Gmail option as well.

Comment: Hey I have done SMTP but i am also getting null value in custom newsleetter field i dont know why ?